# Active Record passing a parameter that is not in a table's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to submit a new project form.

The project has a `name`, `description` and `company_id` columns

a `Project` `belongs_to` a `Company` while a `Company` `has_many` `projects`.

The tricky thing is I also want the company to be able to add a worker in the new view when creating a project.

a `Project` `has_one` `Worker` & a `Worker` `belongs_to` a `Project`

My `Worker` has a `name`, `client_id` & a `project_id` columns

I am having trouble being able to create the Worker on the Project from the new project view since the Project has no Worker column and no param associated to it. How can I pass the worker to the project upon creation so that if I were to call @project.contractor I would get the contractor assigned to that project?

Comment: take a look at accepts_nested_attributes_for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Check out documentation on `accepts_nested_attributes_for` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html and on nested forms http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: your project only has name, description and company_id; therefore, you can't assign to the project any worker. Instead, you assign to the worker... a certain project.

Comment: if your way is one project to one worker and one worker to one project then upon creation of a new project, you create a new worker... but if it is possible to have one worker with many projects then you can re-assign the existing employee upon creation of another project.

LOGIC:
new_proj
new_employee
new_employee=new_proj

new_proj
existing_employee=new_proj